# login and logout doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, logout

I have asp.net web site whit this folder structure ,

```
-MainFolder
   -Account
      -Login.aspx
      -Register.aspx
   -Script
   -Styles
   -userControls
   -About.aspx
   -Home.aspx
   -Site.master
   -Web.config
```

My problem is , when I go to `Login.aspx` page and log in ,  It's redirect to `default.aspx`.
 (What I want is , if I log in from `About.aspx` , after login successful , I want to redirect to `About.aspx` )

And when I log out , it's redirect to `http://localhost:-----/MainFolder/`(Directory Listing -- /MainFolder/) .
( What I want is , If I log out from `About.aspx` , after log out successful , I want to redirect to `About.aspx` ) .
How can I fix it ?

Comment: You want to fix what?

Comment: I've edit my question Soner :)

Comment: Did you tried Membership Provider.?

Comment: Yes I use `Membership Provider` Kaushik !

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you?  Do you still need some help with this problem you're facing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using some of the default set up for an ASP.NET web application project.  Try setting the "DestinationPageURL" property of the `asp:Login` control that's on the Login.aspx page:

Markup (notice I added the `onloggedin="LoginUser_LoggedIn"` to the end):

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" 
        RenderOuterTable="false" DestinationPageUrl="~/About.aspx"
        OnLoggedIn="LoginUser_LoggedIn" >
```

---

You could also handled the "LoggedIn" event for that same Login control:

```
protected void LoginUser_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("../About.aspx");
}
```

Comment: @zey I don't understand what you're telling me.  Do you mean that this solution doesn't work?